# confused with the object creation

Tags: c++, object

I was just reading one article and came through the below code

```
int var  = int();
```

can anyone please let me know what is the importance of following the above concept instead of going for creating an object using new operator or general stack object .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax also **value-initializes** the variable. It's equivalent to writing `int var = 0;`.

A simple `int var;` wouldn't do that (in most contexts) - it would leave the variable uninitialized.

`new` would dynamically allocate the object and should only be used when really necessary.

Comment: Asked 1 min ago, answered 55 secs ago??

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : In this case whether the operator () has been overloaded or the constructor of int has been called ?

Comment: @Learner int's pseudo-constructor. Since it's not a class, it doesn't have a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code avoids getting warnings like "Value not initiated" or getting default NULL values. It's like giving you an assurance that you are not working on a vaiable that does not exist at all.

Comment: Um, "Value not initialized" is not an error. It's legal code, and sometimes useful. If your compiler warns you about that, and you find it useful, fine.

Comment: yeah, it's important in debugging, I should have said warning